# compilation error: variable has incomplete type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

This is the make error:

```
In file included from /Users/ingmar/src/maxr/src/game/data/map/map.cpp:32:
/Users/ingmar/src/maxr/src/game/data/model.h:221:22: error: variable has incomplete type
      'cPlayerBasicData'
                                cPlayerBasicData basicPlayerData;
                                                 ^
/Users/ingmar/src/maxr/src/game/data/player/player.h:48:7: note: forward declaration of
      'cPlayerBasicData'
class cPlayerBasicData;
      ^
```

I'll try to include the relevant code.

model.h:

```
...
#include "game/data/player/player.h"
...
class cPlayerBasicData;
...
class cModel
{
    ...
    template<typename T>
    void load(T& archive)
    {
        ...
        for (auto& player : playerList)
        {
            if (player == nullptr)
            {
                cPlayerBasicData basicPlayerData; // <- this is line 221
                player = std::make_shared<cPlayer>(basicPlayerData, *unitsData);
            }
```

player.h:

```
...
class cPlayerBasicData; // <- this is line 48
...
class cPlayer
{
    ...
```

player.h is included in model.h, thus cPlayerBasicData is effectively forward declared twice. Is this what the error is about?

Comment: The error is about the fact that `cPlayerBasicData` is merely declared, but not actually defined anywhere.

Comment: Actually cPlayerBasicData is defined in playerbasicdata.h. I don't know how they are supposed to come together.

Comment: Declaring it, one could make pointers to it, but actually instantiating it requires more information that is not preceding in one's compilation unit.

Comment: When compiling with gcc it did not care about this error. Could this be because basicPlayerData is not instantiated?

Comment: They are supposed to come together by way of `#include "playerbasicdata.h"` , of course.

Comment: @user1785730 yes, it would have to not be instantiated if it compiled correctly.

Comment: What is the most conservative way of dealing with this error? (This is not my code and it's huge. I don't want to fix everything.)

Comment: Comment out `model.h:221`, but that's probably going to lead to more errors. @IgorTandetnik's solution of finding a header file that defines it and including it before `map.cpp:32` is probably the most promising.

Comment: Ok thanks, that did the trick.